# ASP.NET Core 3 - Web.config with both Kestrel and IIS Express?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, web-config

I have a web.config file that looks similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            ....
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development"/>
        <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1"/>
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This works with IIS Express, but with Kestrel it fails with: `ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.webServer.`

Following the example https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22, I can fix it by putting `<system.webServer>` inside a `location` tag, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" />
      </handlers>

      <!-- hostingModel is the new property here -->
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll"    
                  stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                  hostingModel="InProcess" />

    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

But this configuration fails on IIS Express with a similar error.

So what is the solution here? I want to use 1 web.config for both deployments, and I don't know how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, that's odd, seeing as how Kestrel doesn't use Web.config in the first place. Did you create a custom config provider that loads Web.config?

Comment: @ChrisPratt web.config is copied to be YourFile.dll.config during build, and it picks it up from there.

Comment: No, I mean it *literally* does not use it. Any form of XML configuration file, regardless of the name.

Comment: Hm. My program main is just:

        `public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }`

And this throws the exception `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Configuration system failed to initialize'` with the reason I originally cited. Add `location` to web.config (which becomes XX.dll.config) solves it.

Comment: Are you running just Kestrel, like from a command-line, or are you running in IIS as out of process?

Comment: I'm just using Visual Studio 2019 and changing the drop down from IIS Express to the exe instead (to invoke kestrel).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195933/discussion-between-chris-pratt-and-automaton).